# Mask-RCNN, ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (70) into shape (1)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, mask, valueerror

I am working on a project that detects buildings on SpaceNet dataset by using Mask-RCNN. When I run this code:

```py
model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val, 
            learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE, 
            epochs=1, 
            layers='heads')
```

## I got this  error:

```
    1772             batch_images[b] = mold_image(image.astype(np.float32), config)

-> 1773             batch_gt_class_ids[b, :gt_class_ids.shape[0]] = gt_class_ids

   1774             batch_gt_boxes[b, :gt_boxes.shape[0]] = gt_boxes

   1775             batch_gt_masks[b, :, :, :gt_masks.shape[-1]] = gt_masks
```

## ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (70) into shape (1)

And also got this warning:
[image: Warning Messages]

When I debug the variables: 'gt_class_ids' and 'batch_gt_class_ids',
I got this:

[image: Debug Image]

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error on line 1775 "batch_gt_masks[b, :, :, :gt_masks.shape[-1]] = gt_masks", now, why could that be occurring?

Answer (score 1):

As @Mahesh said, I debugged the variable `gt_class_ids` and realized that the shape of it was (x, 1). 'x' could be 70, 15 or whatever it is, the problem was about the `gt_class_ids.shape[0]` part. `gt_class_ids.shape[0]` gives us 'x', and x again can be any number. So I went to the

> model.py
>
> (The direction of mine was: C:\Users\MUSTAFAAKTAS\Desktop\SpaceNet_MaskRCNN\mrcnn\model.py)

file and changed to `batch_gt_class_ids[b, :gt_class_ids.shape[1]] = gt_class_ids`

instead `batch_gt_class_ids[b, :gt_class_ids.shape[0]] = gt_class_ids`.

So, it return '1' instead of 'x'.

This solution worked for me :)

Comment: Another solution is to watch out what size of array you passed to that code.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (70) into shape (1)` means that there is an array shape mismatch in the line 1773 `batch_gt_boxes[b, :gt_boxes.shape[0]] = gt_boxes` to be more specific your trying to broadcast values from an array of shape 70 to an array of shape 1.

Can you run a debugger on this script and share the value of `gt_class_ids` and `batch_gt_class_ids`? This can help solve the problem better. Thanks